# Get error when getting current date using NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to get the current date with `NSDateComponents`. (I will then be changing the weeks, months, etc.) Here is the code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar component:(NSCalendarUnitCalendar |
                                                        NSCalendarUnitYear |
                                                        NSCalendarUnitMonth |
                                                        NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

`Xcode` gives me the following warning:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSDateComponents *__string' with an expression of type...'
```

And Error:

```
Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'NSDateComponents *' is disallowed with ARC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `component` method (which returns a single numeric component value), and you meant to call `components` (which returns the full `NSDateComponents` object).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Use `component` to add 1 unit you want to access.
Use `components` for more than one unit.